# Comparing changes across two matrices

Tags: r, phylogeny

I'm performing some biogeographic analyses in R and the result is encoded as a pair of matrices. Columns represent geographic regions, rows indicate nodes in a phylogenetic tree and values in the matrix are the probability that the branching event occurred in the geographic region indicated by the column. A very simple example would be:

```
> One_node<-matrix(c(0,0.8,0.2,0),
+                nrow=1, ncol=4,
+                dimnames = list(c("node 1"),
+                                c("A","B","C","D")))
> One_node
       A  B   C  D
node_1 0 0.8 0.2 0
```

In this case, the most probable location for node_1 is region B. In reality, the output of the analysis is encoded as two separate 79x123 matrices. The first is the probabilities of a node occupying a given region before an event and the second is the probabilities of a node occupying a given region after an event (rowSums=1). Some slightly more complicated examples:

```
before<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0.9,
                 0.8,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.07,
                 0.2,0.8,0.4,0.6,0.03,
                 0,0,0,0,0),
                 nrow=5, ncol=4,
                 dimnames = list(c("node_1","node_2","node_3","node_4","node_5"),
                                 c("A","B","C","D")))

after<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0.9,
                0.2,0.8,0.4,0.6,0.03,
                0.8,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.07,
                0,0,0,0,0),
                nrow=5, ncol=4,
                dimnames = list(c("node_1","node_2","node_3","node_4","node_5"),
                              c("A","B","C","D")))

> before
         A    B    C D
node_1 0.0 0.80 0.20 0
node_2 0.0 0.20 0.80 0
node_3 0.0 0.60 0.40 0
node_4 0.0 0.40 0.60 0
node_5 0.9 0.07 0.03 0
> after
         A    B    C D
node_1 0.0 0.20 0.80 0
node_2 0.0 0.80 0.20 0
node_3 0.0 0.40 0.60 0
node_4 0.0 0.60 0.40 0
node_5 0.9 0.03 0.07 0
```

Specifically, I'm only interested in extracting row numbers where column B is the highest in `before` and column C is the highest in `after` and vice versa as I'm trying to extract node numbers in a tree where taxa have moved B->C or C->B.

So the output I'm looking for would be something like:

```
> BC
[1] 1 3
> CB
[1] 2 4
```

There will be rows where B>C or C>B but where neither is the highest in the row (node_5) and I need to ignore these. The row numbers are then used to query a separate dataframe that provides the data I want.

I hope this all makes sense. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
maxBefore <- apply(before, 1, which.max) #find highest columns before (by row)
maxAfter <- apply(after, 1, which.max) #and highest columns after

BC <- which(maxBefore==2 & maxAfter==3) #rows with B highest before, C after
CB <- which(maxBefore==3 & maxAfter==2) #rows with C highest before, B after

BC
node_1 node_3 
     1      3 
CB
node_2 node_4 
     2      4
```

Comment: Excellent, this does exactly what I asked for but has just revealed to me that I didn't in fact really understand my problem! Thanks!